# Content from one div to the other on click - delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a simple function that takes content from one div and put it to the other when specified element is clicked. I did it for the image caption in my slider. So, when you click arrow which is an anchor, then content from div 'orbit-caption' assigned to the 'active' slide is put to the other one 'image-caption'.

```
<ul class="projects-slider" data-orbit>
  <li>
    <img src="img/projects/1.jpg" alt="slide 1" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">
    Text 1
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/projects/2.jpg" alt="slide 2" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">
    Text 2
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/projects/3.jpg" alt="slide 3" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">
    Text 3
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/projects/4.jpg" alt="slide 4" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">
    Text 4
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/projects/5.jpg" alt="slide 5" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">
    Text 5
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="orbit-prev"><span></span></a>
<a href="#" class="orbit-next"><span></span></a>

<footer><div class="img-caption"></div></footer>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var caption = $('li.active .orbit-caption').html();
$('.img-caption').text(caption);

$('.orbit-container a').click(function() {

var caption = $('li.active .orbit-caption').html();
$('.img-caption').text(caption);

});


});
</script>
```

The problem is that click is delayed, I mean that when I click once, my image got description of previous one. Could someone help me with this problem and show how to simplify my function?

Comment: Please post a complete code example, including the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: Hard to see what is going on without HTML and CSS. Create a code snippet or post a JSFiddle

Comment: Not related to the answer, but `$('.something').click(function(){}).trigger('click')` to avoid repeating code

Comment: This code should be executed after the change of the `active` class for those `li` elements. But without seeing more code we are blind.

Comment: Excuse me for that, I uploaded more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want ?

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/5o3aa225/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.img-caption').text($('li.active .orbit-caption').html());

    $('.orbit-next,.orbit-prev').click(function() {
        var currentLi = $('li.active'),
            newLi = $(this).hasClass('orbit-next') ? currentLi.next() : currentLi.prev();

        if(newLi.length){
            currentLi.removeClass('active');
            newLi.addClass('active');
            $('.img-caption').text(newLi.find('.orbit-caption').html());
        }
    });
});
```

You also can use the settings of the orbit slider ([Orbit Doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html#advanced)) and add your function as a callback (`after_slide_change`) :

```
$(document).foundation({
  orbit: {
    animation: 'slide',
    timer_speed: 1000,
    pause_on_hover: false,
    animation_speed: 500,
    navigation_arrows: true,
    timer: false,
    bullets: false,
    slide_number: false,
    slide_number_text: 'of',
    swipe: true,
    variable_height: 'auto',
    after_slide_change : function(){
        $('.img-caption').text($('li.active').find('.orbit-caption').html());
    }
  }
});
```

Or you can use the event `after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit` ([Orbit Doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html#events))

```
$('[data-orbit]').on("after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit", function(event, orbit) {
    $('.img-caption').text($('li.active').find('.orbit-caption').html());
});
```

Or

```
$('[data-orbit]').on("after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit", function(event, orbit) {
    $('.img-caption').text($('.orbit-caption').eq(orbit.slide_number).html());
});
```

Comment: Not excatly, i don't need to add and remove class 'active', it's done by the another script. I just wanted to check if it's class active and what caption belong to this active slide to put it content into another div. Anyway thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Ok. Which slider script do you use ? Maybe you can listen a specific event triggered by this script.

Comment: Okey, I think it will be better to understand my problem with the real example, so here is the link to the slider http://bit.ly/1n785ls -> After first 7 slides, scrolled with the right arrow, caption should changed, but it will after 8 slide - this is way i called it delay.

Comment: Because the 7 first slides have the exact same caption "Adaptacja hali na centrum wspinaczkowe - Murall - Waraszawa Żerań" so it updates the sentence but you can't see it because it's seven times the same sentence. I changed it in the console and add a different number to each slide to check and when I slide it works fine.

Comment: Yes, those 7 slides needs to have the same name, because it's kind of category, but when we move to the 8 slide, it should have another caption like "DWUPOZIOMOWE MIESZKANIE DLA DWOJGA- DĄBROWKA", and it's like this with every slide starting new - let's say - category.

Comment: With my last changes and proposals, is it working as you expected ?

Comment: thank you very much man! this is extacly what i needed :) i've choosen second version :)